# How to replace a character in an interval delimited by two other characters from a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, text-editing

I have to replace all occurrences of the vertical bar character `|` with a comma `,` when they appear between `[` and `]` characters,
on each line of a file.

Let's say I have the below string in the file:

```
wah wah| [go great|no great|so great] | wah wah | [go great|no great|so great]
```

I want my output to be like below:

```
wah wah| [go great,no great,so great] | wah wah | [go great,no great,so great]
```

Note that there can be multiple `[`...`]` pairs. 
Vertical bars between the first `]` and the second `[` should not be changed.

How I can achieve this using shell commands? I tried several ways like below, but nothing worked.

```
sed '/[/,/]/s/|/,/g' abcd.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
sed ': loop; s/\(\[[^][]*\)|\([^][]*\]\)/\1,\2/; t loop' input_file
```

What’s up?

- `: loop` is a label for looping; I’ll use it in a moment.
- `s/\(\[[^][]*\)|\([^][]*\]\)/\1,\2/` replaces *one* `|` that appears
  between `[` and `]` with a comma. 
  Broken down:

  ```
  s/  \(  \[  [^][]  *  \)  |  \(  [^][]  *  \]  \)  /  \1,\2  /
  ```

  - `\(`…`\)` delimits a search & replace group. 
    Given a `[`…`]` with a `|` between them,
    this matches the `[` *up **to*** (but not including) the (last) `|`
    as one group,
    and everything after the `|` up *through* (including) the `]` as a second group.
  - `\[` matches a literal `[`.
  - `[^][]` matches any character other than `[` or `]`. 
    It breaks down as

    ```
    [  ^  ][  ]
    ```

    i.e., an instance of

    ```
    [^characters_to_not_match]
    ```
  - `*` — zero or more characters other than `[` or `]`.
  - `\)` — end of group; discussed above.
  - `|` is a literal `|` (the one we want to replace).
  - The second half of the regular expression
    is almost the same as the first half:
    match a group consisting of zero or more characters other than `[` or `]`,
    followed by a `]`.
  - Then replace all that with the first group, a comma, and the second group. 
    Since everything in the matched string is in one of the groups,
    except for the `|`, this functionally replaces the `\` with the `,`.
- `t loop` — test/transfer. 
  If the `s` command found a match and made a substitution,
  go back to the label and try again
  (because the `s` command replaces only one `|` at a time). 
  If it didn’t find a match,
  terminate the command script and go on to the next line.